# FileZilla Pro with S3 using STS credentials

Tags: amazon-s3, filezilla

Is it possible to use [AWS STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html) (*Security Token Service*) credentials with FileZilla Pro to access an [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket?

The [IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html) policy we have on one of the accounts enforces [MFA](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/mfa/) usage, so the normal *access key* / *`secret key`* can only be used to generate a MFA-authenticated STS session, with a temporary access/secret key and token. When configuring FileZilla, I see a spot for the access/secret keys, but not the STS token value.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 3.49.1 (July 15, 2020) FileZilla Pro [supports](https://filezillapro.com/filezilla-pro-adds-support-for-openstack-swift-keystone-v3-onedrive-and-amazon-sts/) STS provided credentials with or without MFA.

Here is an article from FileZilla's Knowledge Base that may help you with your question:

- [How Amazon Security Token Service (STS)
  Works](https://filezillapro.com/docs/v3/cloud/amazon-security-token-service/)